# Borrar valores guardados (Tags) de campo <datalist> en html

Tags: html5, datalist

```html
<form name="formulario" id="formulario" action="/demos/2013/05-html-form-datalist.php" method="POST">
    <!-- La datalist con id 'listas' y sus diferentes valores -->
    Escribe un color (Azul, rojo, amarrillo, negro, verde): 
    <datalist id="listas">
        <option value="azul">
        <option value="rojo">
        <option value="amarillo">
        <option value="negro">
        <option value="verde">
    </datalist>
 
    <!-- Asociamos al input la datalist 'listas' -->
    <input name="color" list="listas">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Tengo un problema con un campo  en html. Yo escribo en el campo y con un evento onkeypress voy llamando a una función para hacer una busqueda de nombres.

El problema con el campo  es que cuando voy escribiendo en el para hacer una búsqueda con el texto que escribo, la lista me muestra algunos nombres que yo ya he escrito antes. No quiero que pase eso por que si el usuario pincha en ese nombre, no es un elemento de la lista y no me guarda su valor.
En el ejemplo a ejecutar, si yo escribo "morado" un par de veces, vereis que noes un color que esté en la lista pero esta te lo muestra.

**Este es el campo html**

```
<label  class="col-md-1 control-label">Proveedor:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type = "text" class= "left-align form-control input-sm"  list="entidadesLst"  id="idProveedorPT" size="38" >
            <datalist id="entidadesLst">
            </datalist>
            </div>
```

**Aqui cargo la lsita de forma dinámica**

```
objJson = JSON.parse(data);
   $.each(objJson, function (i, item) {
        entidad+="<option    data-ejemplo='"+objJson[i].id +"' value='" 
       +objJson[i].name+"'  label='"+objJson[i].cif+"'>  ";
     });
    $('#entidadesLst').html(entidad);
```

Answer (score 0):

pues seleccionas por id el data list

```
var ls = document.getElementById("listas");
```

y remueves todos los hijos

```
var numChilds = s.children.length;
for(var i=0;i<numChilds;i++){
  s.children[0].remove() 
}
```

Comment: Esto no funciona

Answer (score 0):

En el `input` añade el atributo `autocomplete = "off"`